# Web.Pages.Shared.Components razor component not found in razor page

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, razor-components

I've added a MyRazorComponent.razor component to my Web/Pages/Shared/Components/MyRazorComponent folder, but when I try to reference it in my Index.cshtml in the Web/Pages/MyRazorPage folder, the Index page doesn't compile because it says the Components in the Web.Pages.Shared.Components path does not exist ("The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Web.Pages.Shared' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

I tried adding @using Web.Pages.Shared.Components to my _Imports.razor in the Components folder, but I got the same compiler error in the _Imports.razor page, as well as in the Index page.  I also tried moving the _Imports.razor up to the Shared and Pages folder and neither of those worked.

Strangely intellisense walked me right to it, but the compiler doesn't see it.

As always, the razor view components work fine when their Components folder is created in the Web/Pages folder.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 ver 16.3.6, .NET Core 3.0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating the Components folder for the razor components in the root of the Web folder (i.e. it didn't work when I created it in the Web/Pages/Shared folder), then it all works as expected/documented.

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me. otherwise, it sounds like we have the same problem, but no matter where I put the folder it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add **@using `Web.Pages.Shared.Components`** to your _Imports.razor

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it gave the same error in the _Imports.razor page

Comment: same issue. this didn't solve it.